# how to put multiple oracle_home for different oracle products

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, soa, oracle-home

I am working on Oracle fmw and Oracle database.
both are installed in different directory. but as of now i need to put ORACLE_HOME of their installed location. 
please suggest me how to put 2 different locations in one environment variable.

Comment: What platform are you on (Linux, Windows, something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to put them in oracle home, you let them install.

later the software config file will decide which `oracle_home` to took!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you can't and should have no need to do so.  Environment variables are set at the session level.  You set it for the ORACLE_HOME that is appropriate for the product you are dealing with at the moment, in that session.